# のことです　のです difference

Tags: grammar

I struggle to understand the differences between this two sentences, for me both « のです » and « のことです » emphasis explanation …

> 町屋は京都にある古い木の家のことだ。
> 町屋は京都にある古い木の家のです。

Comment: The second sentence does not really work. The particular sentence is used in the same sense as [Providing definitions/explanations with というのは ～のこと/ということだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24092)